# OpenCV saving Depth and RGB-Stream

Tags: video, kinect, depth

I want to use OpenCV in order to save depth-data and rgb-stream. I know it is also possible with OpenNI (.oni) but i just want to use OpenCV. Is it possible to write for each frame the depth data to a .xml file and the rgb-stream to a .png for example. And after that read the .xml and .png files back in with imread for example in order to have the depth map and the rgb stream connected again as a video sequence? Or do you have a better solution to generate a depth+rgb video from kinect data with OpenCV?

I would be very thankful for ideas or code snippets. Thanks.

Comment: Opencv has a built in openNI wrapper: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_highgui.html You can also use libfreenect or official microsoft kinect sdk to decode the image if you completely reject openni. In short opencv doesnt support kinect device without 3rd party additions

Comment: I am just using the Kinect for the first steps and and would like to work on a ToF-Camera afterwards which is not supported by OpenNI.  That is the main reason why I'm searching for an alternative so I can make use of that for an alternative Camera-type. Thx

Comment: Why do you not use the Kinect Studio to capture and replay depth and color data?